# Are the French word genou and the word génération cognate?

Tags: étymologie

Are the French word genou (knee) and the French word génération cognate because of the Latin word genu "knee" in the Genetive case has the form genus and this is the case birth (the generation of the new case)?

I have deleted my previous post.

Answer (score 5):

Not at all.

- Genou is from latin genuculum (genou) : https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/genou/36600?q=genou#36551
- Génération is from latin generatio (engendrer) : https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/g%c3%a9n%c3%a9ration/36537?q=g%c3%a9n%c3%a9ration#36491